# Can you coerce Some(box|:|) to Option<Box<FnOnce<...>>> in rust?

Tags: rust

As per the title. Can you? Or does it require an intermediary step for the trait cast?

I realize that the closure reform isn't completely done yet, and there are a number of open bugs with it.

However, the bug tracker is so completely full of bugs and RFCs and links to obsolete and new tickets, I'm having a very hard time trying to understand the state of play with the new unboxed closures in rust.

This works:

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures, unboxed_closure_sugar)]
#![allow(dead_code, unused_variables)]

fn test(bar:Box<FnOnce<(int,), ()> + Send>) {
  bar.call_once((10,));
}

fn main() {
  let bar:Box<FnOnce<(int,), ()> + Send> = box |:x:int| { println!("Hi:{}", x); };
  test(bar);

  test(box |:x:int| { println!("Hi:{}", x); });
}
```

and this works:

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures, unboxed_closure_sugar)]
#![allow(dead_code, unused_variables)]

fn test2(mut bar:Option<Box<FnOnce<(int,), ()> + Send>>) {
  bar.take().unwrap().call_once((10,));
}

fn main() {
  let bar2:Box<FnOnce<(int,), ()> + Send> = box |:x:int| { println!("Hi:{}", x); };
  test2(Some(bar2));
}
```

However, this doesn't work for some reason:

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures, unboxed_closure_sugar)]
#![allow(dead_code, unused_variables)]

fn test2(mut bar:Option<Box<FnOnce<(int,), ()> + Send>>) {
  bar.take().unwrap().call_once((10,));
}

fn main() {
  test2(Some(box |:x:int| { println!("Hi:{}", x); }));
}
```

Error:

```
foo.rs:21:9: 21:53 error: mismatched types: expected `core::option::Option<Box<core::ops::FnOnce<(int,), ()>+Send>>`, found `core::option::Option<Box<closure>>` (expected trait core::ops::FnOnce, found closure)
foo.rs:21   test2(Some(box |:x:int| { println!("Hi:{}", x); }));
```

So, question:

1) *Should* the above code work? Or does `Option<>`/`Some()` imply something complex that I haven't understood in this context?

2) If so, is there an open ticket for implicit conversions between the `|:|` sugar and `FnOnce` types?

(because https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18101 seems to suggest it should be done, which is why example #1 works, but I've gotten completely lost trying to hunt through that meta bug to find any specific bug referring to the closure sugar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is worth noting that this is a general property of trait objects and generic structs/enums, and is not at all specific to unboxed closures, `FnOnce`, `Option` or `|:|` (especially not this, since it is just a nice way to create a value implementing a certain trait).

Also, the recent [RFC #401](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0401-coercions.md) is related.

> 1) Should the above code work? Or does Option<>/Some() imply something complex that I haven't understood in this context?

`Box<FnOnce<..>>` is a trait object and so does not have the same representation or type as a non-dynamic `Box<F>` for `F: FnOnce<...>`. Theoretically we could support fancier deep coercions through enums and structs for some types, but it wouldn't necessarily play well/uniformly with co- and contra-variance.

In any case, you can do a normal trait object cast:

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures, unboxed_closure_sugar)]
#![allow(dead_code, unused_variables)]

fn test2(mut bar:Option<Box<FnOnce<(int,), ()> + Send>>) {
  bar.take().unwrap().call_once((10,));
}

fn main() {
  test2(Some((box |: x| println!("Hi:{}", x)) as Box<FnOnce(int)+Send>));
}
```

On the note about variance, consider:

```
enum Option2<T> {
    Empty,
    One(fn() -> T)
}
```

That is, it either stores nothing or it stores a function that returns a `T`. What does it mean to cast `Option2<Box<X>>` to `Option2<Box<Trait>>`? One cannot just forcibly pretend that a function returning `Box<X>` returns a value of type `Box<Trait>`.

> 2) If so, is there an open ticket for implicit conversions between the |:| sugar and FnOnce types?

The `|:|` sugar is a `FnOnce`-implementing type. `FnOnce` is a trait and coercions happen like any other trait object.

Comment: Actually it is not possible to coerce to `FnOnce` (that is, use `FnOnce` as a trait object) as `FnOnce` is not object-safe (the `call_once` method takes `self` by-value). The current workaround is to use `std::thunk::Invoke<A,R>` as a trait object, and call the `invoke()` method, which takes self as a `Box<Self>`, so is object-safe. More details in [this blog post](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/11/26/purging-proc/).

Comment: @Vaelden, that is very true, however this answer was written before object safety was a thing (meaning `Box<F>` -> `Box<FnOnce()>` was legal), and, in any case, the problem described is still a problem with object safe traits.